# Porting peripheral to AndroidThings - pin selection

Tags: porting, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I’m attempting to port some code to AndroidThings. Currently it uses “GPIO 3 (SCL)” as a pin on the Raspberry Pi. https://github.com/mattdh666/rpi-led-matrix-panel/blob/master/RgbMatrix.h#L206

However on AndroidThings the same pin is “I2C1 (SCL)” so I cannot reference it using `peripheralManService.openGpio("BCM3")`
[see here for Pinout diagram](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi-io.html)

```
    try {
        gpioSerialClock = service.openGpio("BCM3"); // Throws Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Unknown I/O name BCM3
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
```

Should I move my wire to use another pin on the Raspberry Pi that is labelled for GPIO? Is there any consequences to that :/ my peripheral wants to use BCM3 as it is the serial clock

[image]

Some more visual explanation of the pin selected if needed:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are porting assumes that all the pins connected are pure GPIO pins. It explicitly drives all the pin transitions for each one. In that regard, you simply need 13 available GPIO ports to connect to the RGB Matrix. You just have to make the appropriate adjustments to your wiring to match the pin numbers in the example with the ports you've chosen instead.

This is not the most efficient way to handle the communication from Android Things (lots of round trips and looping over the I/O), but it should work as a start. Ideally, you would drive the clocked serial data from an SPI or I2C bus (if the protocols match) to reduce the overhead and improve the transfer rate.